# Setting up php to send email through IIS

Tags: email, php, smtp, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8

I have a wordpress site on my Windows 2012 R2 IIS server. I have installed SMTP.

These are the setting I've done in php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = support@mydomain.com
```

I also set up IIS as such:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I set up the site's SMTP as such:

[image]

I have restarted the server in case I missed something that needed to be restarted. I do not see any errors in the IIS or SMTP logs. I don't see any reference to the send at all.

Am I missing something?